# how to fix "model.findByIdAndUpdate' not updating documents in mongodb 4.0?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm learning expressjs and i'm trying to update a document in my mongodb database by id and using PUT to specify a route, after entering this command in the terminal:

```
curl -X PUT --data "name =James&age = 20&nationality=American"http://localhost:3000/people/5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131
```

It prints out the document but nothing has been updated

I have used {new:true} as recommended against the default setting ({new:false}) however nothing has changed. without specifying any route it works 
e.g

```js
Person.findOneAndUpdate({name:'deean'},{age:34},function(err,response){
   console.log(response);
});
```

the above code works
but this doesn't:

```js
app.put('/people/:id', function(req, res){
   Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true} ,function(err, response){
      if(err) 
       res.json({message:"Error in updating person with id" + req.params.id});
      res.json(response);
      });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

the original document i am trying to change is

```
{ _id: 5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131,
name: 'deean ajashi',
age: 34,
nationality: 'indian',
__v: 0 } ]
```

this is the output i'm getting on the terminal

```
    C:\Users\Diola>curl -X PUT --data "name = James&age = 20&nationality = American" http://localhost:3000/people/5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131

{"_id":"5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131","name":"dean ajashi","age":34,"nationality":"indian","__v":0}
C:\Users\Diola>
```

The format i'm using is from Tutorialspoint[click to check out page on Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_database.htm)

edit: i think this is what you mean by model and router file though i'm not sure

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer(); 
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static('public')); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', { useNewUrlParser: true }); 
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   nationality: String 
});
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
app.get('/person', function(req, res){
   res.render('person'); 
});
app.post('/person', function(req, res){ 
   var personInfo = req.body; 
   console.log('recived your request'); 
   console.log(req.body);
   
   
   if(!personInfo.name || !personInfo.age || !personInfo.nationality){ 
      res.render('show_message', {
         message: "Sorry, you provided worng info", type: "error"});
   } else {
      var newPerson = new Person({  
         name: personInfo.name,
         age: personInfo.age,
         nationality: personInfo.nationality
      });

  newPerson.save(function(err, Person){ 
         if(err)
            res.render('show_message', {message: "Database error", type: "error"});
         else
            res.render('show_message', {
               message: "New person added", type: "success", person: personInfo});
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass `{new: true}` it returns the updated document (*Vs*) old document if it's false it has nothing to do with update operation, Can you give us your model and router file, meanwhile - try below code & check if you're able to get request by printing `req.params.id` and `req.body` :

```
app.put('/people/:id', function(req, res){
   Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set:req.body}, {new: true} ,function(err, response){
       if(err) res.json({message: "Error in deleting record id " + req.params.id});
       else res.json(response);
      });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I added the file you asked to see, the code worked, but it gave the same result, what do you mean by request. Did you mean findByIdAndDelete?

Comment: @diola.O : Can you print req.params.id and req.body after this line : app.put('/people/:id', function(req, res){ using console log and check what's happening or try the same with replacing Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id :req.params.id},..................

Comment: i did the first and it printed out the id in the console but the for findOneAndUpdate all i got was 'null'

Comment: what about the req.body can you give me both here, it shouldn't matter whether findOneAndUpdate or findByIdAndUpdate for printing request,& also replace {new:true} with {returnNewDocument: true} when you're using findOneAndUpdate. if output is null maybe it's not able to update any document, can you give me requests exactly what is being printed..

Comment: app.put('/people/:id', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.params.id);
   Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:req.body},{new: true} ,function(err, response){
       if(err) res.json({message: "Error in deleting record id " + req.params.id});
       else res.json(response);
      });
});                                                                                                                                output:    5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131

Comment: and                                                                                                                                              app.put('/people/:id', function(req, res){
   Person.findOneAndUpdate({__id:req.params.id},{$set:req.body},{returnNewDocument: true} ,function(err, response){
       if(err) res.json({message: "Error in deleting record id " + req.params.id});
       else res.json(response);
      });
}); output:null

Comment: Can you please execute this and let know what's printed with 'Printing req::'  :: app.put('/people/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Printing req::', req.params.id,',', req.body ) 
    Person.findOneAndUpdate({ __id: req.params.id }, { $set: req.body },
         { returnNewDocument: true }, function (err, response) { 
             if (err) res.json({ message: "Error in deleting record id " + req.params.id }); 
             else res.json(response); 
            }); 
        });

Comment: This was the output in the console Printing req:: 5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131 , { 'name ': ' James', 'age ': ' 20', 'nationality ': ' American' },                                                   but it didn't change in the database

Comment: @diola.O : Can you add this to your schema ::::::> _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId . Also why is age getting printed as string? make age : Mixed .

Comment: var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   nationality: String                                                                                                        its still printing null on terminal and the previous output on console. as for the string i'm not sure why but its a number in the database

Comment: really sorry, I'm not sure what's happening, Can you add your put method to router and give us entire file, meanwhile can you try like this ::>  curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name" ="James"&"age" = 20&"nationality"="American"}' http://localhost:3000/people/5d3ba2a863ba682d70242131

Comment: @diola.O : Seems like request is coming as string can you do ::> let reqBody = JSON.parse(req.body) and replace {$set:req.body} with {$set: reqBody} . try the same with both findOneAndupdate & findByIdAndUpdate. either one of my last two comments should work !! Please give a try.

Comment: @ srinivas y i posted the entire file, did you see the edit   ?                              recieved this error                                                                                                               curl: (6) Could not resolve host: =James
'age' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'nationality' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Where is you PUT method, I'm not able to see it in your file, also can you try with CURL what ever you've earlier and add this in put func :::> let reqBody = JSON.parse(req.body) and replace {$set:req.body} with {$set: reqBody} . try the same with both findOneAndupdate & findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: i'm using windows 10 , it gave an error 'unexpexted token o', i checked on how to fix it but i haven't been able to get it to work. Also i'm not quite sure what you mean by PUT method, could you give me an idea of what that's supposed to look like?

Comment: I'm talking about app.put the function which you're supposed to use in your code when you're hitting thru curl, is that in your actual file ? Also did you try JSON.parse thing ?